# Json format error, from the php file with request_ajax ()

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, html

Good evening, I have a problem with the json step by ajax, what happens, is that I am sending a json, so that dynamic rendering of html elements with js, came doing the step of this in the same way, the novelty is that apparently the notifications, large blanks, and dangers of the php code is happening as part of my json, and personally I have been trying for two days to solve it and I do not succeed, please if anyone knows any way to pass Just json what I want, please appreciate your help, this is the code:

code php

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

function request_ajax(){
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest';
}

$directorio=" /../../../images/artist/carpeta";

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image_principal"]["name"]);
$newfilename = microtime(true) . '.' . end($temp);
$image1=($newfilename + 1) * mt_getrandmax();


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_principal']['tmp_name'], __DIR__ . $directorio . $image1. $_FILES["image_principal"]["name"])){
         $imagen_urlprincipal= 'artist/'.$image1 . $_FILES["image_principal"]["name"] ;
       }

$temp1 = explode(".", $_FILES["image_biography"]["name"]);
$newfilename1 = microtime(true) . '.' . end($temp1);
$image2=$newfilename1 * mt_getrandmax();

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_biography']['tmp_name'], __DIR__ . $directorio . $image2. $_FILES["image_biography"]["name"])){
         $imagen_urlbiography= 'artist/'.$image2 . $_FILES["image_biography"]["name"] ;
       }


$name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$bio=htmlspecialchars($_POST['biography']);
$birt=htmlspecialchars($_POST['birthdate']);
$deat=htmlspecialchars($_POST['deathdate']);


try {
  require_once('../../functions/conection.php');
  $statement="insert into `artist` values ( null , '{$name}' , '{$imagen_urlprincipal}' , '{$bio}' , '{$birt}' ,'{$deat}', '{$imagen_urlbiography}');";
  $result= $conection->query($statement);


  if (request_ajax()) {
    echo json_encode(array(
      'result'=>$result,
      'name'=> $name,
      'biography'=> $bio,
      'birthDate'=> $birt,
      'deathDate'=> $deat,
      'id_register'=> $conection->insert_id
    ));
  }else {
    exit;
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
 ?>
```

code js:

```
function createRegister(){
  var data= new FormData(form);
  for([key,value] of data.entries()){
    console.log(key+": "+value);
  }
  var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', action, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var result= xhr.response;
      console.log("Resultado: "+ result );
      var json= JSON.parse(result);
      if(json.result==true){
        div_create(json.name);
        template(json.name, json.number, json.id_register);
        totalRegistros.innerHTML=parseInt(totalRegistros.textContent)+1;
      }

    }
  }
  xhr.send(data);

}
```

way it brings the json, and the respective error by console :

```
name: test2
main.js:151 image_principal: [object File]
main.js:151 biography: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
main.js:151 birthdate: 2018-08-09
main.js:151 deathdate: 2018-08-17
main.js:151 image_biography: [object File]
main.js:159 Resultado: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\DOM\secciones\artistas_bcv\crud\create.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\DOM\secciones\artistas_bcv\crud\create.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />





 ?>

{"result":true,"name":"test2","biography":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","birthDate":"2018-08-09","deathDate":"2018-08-17","id_register":29}
VM98:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (main.js:160)
```

Comment: There's an error occurring in your PHP code which results in a notice thrown: _"<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\DOM\secciones\artistas_bcv\crud\create.php</b> on line <b>12</b>"_ which is what messes up your json response. What's on line 12 in your `create.php`-file?

Comment: I'm guessing it's `image1=($newfilename + 1) * mt_getrandmax();` that throws that  notice. The problem is that `$newfilename` doesn't contain a valid number so doing addition on it `+1` will throw that notice. Do a `var_dump($newfilename)` and check what it actually contains. It should be something like `123456.1234.what-ever-end($temp)-returns`. You can't have more than one decimal.

Comment: It is that I had already removed the line, but in any case send many blanks and in the end send the json, the annoying thing is that the xhr.response sends as part of the json the blanks.

Comment: Make sure there's no output in your code and no spaces/new lines before your `<?php`-tag. One single space/line break will mess up the json-parser. If you do get spaces/new lines before your json-output, there is definitely something that outputs those.

Comment: Btw, you are _wide open_ to SQL injections. You should use Prepared statements instead of injecting (unescaped!) user data straight in to the queries like that.